# How to make the method 'charCodeAt' works through the for loop after?

Tags: javascript

I'm programming a hangman game to practice JS, and I need to get the keyCode of an character which is in a position in the array. I'm using the 'charCodeAt' method to do it; it Works really well at the first position (position [0]), however, as it loops through the array, it returns 'NaN' instead of the keyCode of the following characters (it doesn't update on the following position of the array).

I used the 'console.log()' to prove to myself that the characters that are being displayed and the index are looping through the 'for' loop as it goes by, however, for some reason, the variable that receives the keyCode of the character in the current position, doesn't receive it after the second position (position [1]) of the array. I think this part of the code is redundant, but I can't think about another way to do it. Just for the record, these variables are declared in a global scope.

```
for(let i=0; i<theArray.length; i++){
   indexElementValue = theArray[i];
   keyCodeAt = indexElementValue.charCodeAt(i);
   inputElement.addEventListener('keydown', validation);
}

const validation = () => {
   let typing = event.which || event.keyCode;
   if((typing == keyCodeAt) || (typing == 20) || (typing == 32) || (typing == 8) || (typing == 9) || (typing == 13) || (typing == 16)){
   }else{
      console.warn('WRONG');
   }
}
```

I expect the 'keyCodeAt' variable recognizes all of the keyCodes in all positions, instead of recognizing only on the first position and giving me 'NaN' on the others.

Comment: Is it an array of letters or words? Since you're using ```i``` for both the array position and character position, you're essentially iterating over the first character of the first element, then the 2nd char of the 2nd element and so on

Comment: Your code is quite unclear. Why are you adding the event listener inside the for loop? It would be easier if you could make a [mre] using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) so that we can reproduce your issue for ourselves...

Comment: `inputElement.addEventListener('keydown', validation);` inside a loop??? You are binding tons of events. I am not sure what you are expecting that code to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should do either:

```
keyCodeAt = theArray.charCodeAt(i);
```

or (but a bit overkill):

```
indexElementValue = theArray[i];
keyCodeAt = indexElementValue.charCodeAt(0);
```

But with:

```
indexElementValue = theArray[i];
keyCodeAt = indexElementValue.charCodeAt(i);
```

... you are looking beyond the single character that is `indexElementValue`, which only has a character at index 0.

#### Remark

It makes no sense to have this in a loop:

```
inputElement.addEventListener('keydown', validation);
```

It should only be executed once. Note that that statement does not *execute* `validation`. It only tells what the keydown handler is, and so you only need to do that once.

Secondly, the loop is doing nothing with the `keyCodeAt` variable, so there seems no point in getting it.

It would make more sense to skip the whole loop and use the `includes` Array method in the keydown handler:

```
inputElement.addEventListener('keydown', validation);
const validation = (e) => {
   e = e || event;
   let typing = e.which || e.keyCode;
   if(!theArray.includes(typing) && ![20,32,8,9,13,16].includes(typing)) {
      console.warn('WRONG');
   }
}
```

Also make sure to use the event *argument*, as that is the standard. The `event` global object is not defined in all hosts.